# Wrapped text in tables when knitting to pdf using gt

Tags: r-markdown, gt

Sorry if this is a very trivial question but I've looked up and down the internet and can't find an answer. I'm making a basic table using the gt package in markdown. But I can't seem to get the text to wrap when knitting to a *.pdf. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
table_data %>% gt()
```

Comment: Add a piece of code

Comment: thanks, any idea on the content of that code though?

Comment: provide the code for table data

Comment: @randmlaber why don't you use the example code from `gt::` package? e.g.:

```r
# Create a display table showing ten of
# the largest islands in the world
gt_tbl <- gt(islands_tbl)

# Show the gt Table
gt_tbl
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Any luck solving this?

Comment: @EmmanuelTeitelbaum: I ended up going with `kableExtra` instead. With the reproducible working example below, try:
`test %>%
kable() %>%
kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)`

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but a reproducible working example.

````
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r test, echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

test <- data.frame(v1=c(
  "This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string. This is a long string.",
  "This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string. This is a another long string."),
                   v2=c(1, 2))
test %>% gt()
```
````

results in:

[image]

I ended up going with `kableExtra` instead. With the reproducible working example, replace `test %>% gt()` with `test %>% kable() %>% kable_styling(full_width = TRUE)`